# How do I access a COM byte array from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, com, interop

I have a COM interface which has a method which in VB has a signature like this:

```
Public Function GetData() As Byte()
```

In C# it shows as

```
public byte[] GetData();
```

In javascript it is a strange opaque object. Indexing it returns undefined.

```
data[1] == undefined
typeof( data ) == "unknown"
data.Item(1) => error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any way to use the returned object in javascript directly. But since I am in a COM aware environment anyway, I have some microsoft things lying around in the namespace that I can use, namely, the [VBArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/y39d47w8%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) type. It allows you to create and use VB style arrays from javascript. And VB arrays can understand the COM byte array.
So the solution is this:

```
var data = thingy.GetData();
var jsArray = (new VBArray( data )).toArray();
```